# Em outros vs Noutros

Tags: tradução-inglês, morfologia

Traduzindo do inglês

> In some countries is dangerous when people read and own the Bible. In
>   others, they own and don't read.

Para português

> Em alguns países, é perigoso que as pessoas leiam e tenham a Bíblia.
>   **Em outros**, as pessoas têm e não lêem.

Após pensar sobre o assunto fico com uma dúvida se devo usar aglutinação "Noutros" (Em + outros), "Em outros", ou é indiferente (ambos estão corretos)?

Comment: Tem certeza de que está traduzindo *do* inglês? Porque parece o contrário.

Comment: Sim, porquê @stafusa?

Comment: No meu entendimento no mínimo faltam uns "it"s nas frases. Mas não é relevante para a questão.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ambas as formas são corretas: "em outros países" e "noutros países", sendo "noutros", como indicas na questão, a aglutinação da proposição "em" e o pronome indefinido "outros" (em+outros).

Answer (score 2):

Em português europeu, neste caso apenas a forma "noutros" é válida.

Noutras situações, a forma "em outros" também é válida.
Mas não sei explicar porquê a diferença. ‍♀️

---

«Em outros "vs" noutros», em https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/em-outros-vs-noutros/1240

> Tanto é correcto " em outros idiomas", como "noutros idiomas". Em "noutros", temos a aglutinação de em+outros.

---

E [usos atuais online](https://www.google.com/search?q="em+outros"+site%3A+.pt):

https://www.intermarche.pt/ :

> - Utilizamos cookies para melhorar a sua experiência de navegação, e mostrar-lhe conteúdo personalizado segundo os seus interesses, tanto neste site como **em outros** sites de parceiros.

https://www.webhs.pt/blog/marketing/que-dominio-devo-escolher-pt-ou-com/ :

> - Os ccTLDs são na maioria dos casos domínios abertos ao registo por parte dos residentes no país – empresas ou particulares – **em outros** casos são abertos a todos.

Comment: (+1) para a partilha de uns exemplos atuais (ainda que não sejam mesmo iguais). Pois, o ciberduvidas dá razão à resposta atualmente marcada como certa.

Comment: Eu não acho que o ciberdúvidas indique que ambas são válidas; "em outros" soa-me mal. Mas estou disposto a entregar *bounty* a uma resposta que explique, adequada e documentadamente, como é em pt-PT. :-)

Comment: Então força com isso, também gostava de saber.